# "coredata.xts(x) : currently unsupported data type" when creating an xts object

Tags: r, xts, dygraphs

I have been able to create an xts object in the past with basic tables consisting of floats and dates in the POSIX format. Yet I have no idea why the xts function is throwing an error on this type of data. Here is a sample of it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOC05.png)

carries on with 0s until this kind of data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wIm0.png)

My code simply goes as follow

```
graph <- xts(sample$data, order.by = sample$date)
dygraph(graph)
```

And would throw the error I specified in the title of the topic. I am slightly confused as to why that is.

Edit: 
rescaling with dput for test purposes:

```
structure(list(data = list(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), date = structure(c(1543434776.963, 
1542820106.015, 1543615640.482, 1543851212.862, 1543854217.269, 
1543930726.949, 1544030657.079, 1544034770.003, 1544043898.003, 
1544457518.498, 1544460092.511, 1544467414.991, 1544470840.541, 
1544628952.371, 1544473221.584, 1544631972.069, 1544646951.827, 
1544645607.091, 1542833838.068, 1542819507.303), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to make this reproducible i.e. `dput(head(sample, 20))`   is the `sample$date` `POSIXct` class

Comment: added. It is indeed casted to POSIXct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column 'data' is `list` (checked by `str(sample)`), `unlist` it to a `vector` and it should work

```
library(xts)
xts(unlist(sample$data), order.by = sample$date)
#                     [,1]
#2018-11-21 11:58:27    0
#2018-11-21 12:08:26    0
#2018-11-21 15:57:18    0
#2018-11-28 14:52:56    0
#2018-11-30 17:07:20    0
#2018-12-03 10:33:32    0
#2018-12-03 11:23:37    0
#2018-12-04 08:38:46    0
#2018-12-05 12:24:17    0
#2018-12-05 13:32:50    0
#2018-12-05 16:04:58    0
#2018-12-10 10:58:38    0
#2018-12-10 11:41:32    0
#2018-12-10 13:43:34    0
#2018-12-10 14:40:40    0
#2018-12-10 15:20:21    0
#2018-12-12 10:35:52    0
#2018-12-12 11:26:12    0
#2018-12-12 15:13:27    0
#2018-12-12 15:35:51    0
```